# How to check if bathroom fan is compatible with current-leaking timer?

Tags: electrical, exhaust-fan, timer

I installed a timer switch to control my bathroom fan, the Lutron MA-T530G.

This timer connects to the hot wire only and operates in series with the fan. Due to this, it leaks a small current even when the fan is off. This current goes through the fan as well (I suppose the designers must have relied on the fan not being activated by the low current). Apparently some fans don't like this, because my old one broke shortly after I installed the timer. I have also seen people online saying this can break some fans. Apparently this type of timer (with current leak) only works for some fans.

That fan was old and crappy anyway and I have now replaced it with a new fan. The new fan is currently controlled by a regular on/off switch.

I want to install the timer switch again to control the new fan. But how do I know if my new fan is compatible? What spec do I check for this? I don't want to break the new fan too because it's expensive and was a hassle to install.

Comment: I'll bet if you look in the owner's manual there will be some hints. If you're not sure what hints to look for, you might consider telling _us_ what brand/model it is so someone here could tell you. You might also consider buying a timer that _doesn't_ rely on leaking current, since that will be compatible with _any_ vent fan...

Comment: As I've written in many messages, a timer needs to get power from somewhere. But unlike a light timer, a fan timer often just needs "run for a little while after turning it on and then stop", which can be done with a purely **mechanical** timer that needs no electricity. Worth considering, depending on your use case. The other thing is to see whether you have neutral (for the same circuit) in the switch box - if you do then a timer that uses neutral is an option. Timers using "leak current are a big problem now with LED lighting.